# how to Position a div , right next to another div AND on top of all other elements in the dom . jsFiddle provided

Tags: css, html, positioning, css-float

This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntSCr/5/) . When I click the "add your own question button", the #question_types div appears below all the elements .

I want it to appear right next to the "add your own question button" , on top of the "or" word.

Comment: Is it supposed to be inside the surrounding div that the `or` is in? Because if so, it doesn't fit, you applied a set height.

Comment: I just want it right next to the big button ...doesnt matter if "#question_types" div's height exceeds the  surrounding div that the "or" is in

Comment: something like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/ntSCr/6/

Comment: @atlavis: That was exactly what I did, but I thought to myself, 'No, self, that looks like crap!' :)

Comment: @atlavis , yes . just that I dont want the "or" and "Add Question from libaray" links to move when the "#question_types" div is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go http://jsfiddle.net/ntSCr/9/

Comment: that great , I did a little hack myself and came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/upwQ4/1/) . Can you take two mins , and tell which one I should use and why I may be wrong? Thanks a ton.

Comment: It's all about positioning. My solution is flexable - if others' elements size change, then `#question_types div` will adjust. You use fixed positioning (like `top: -70px; left: 220px;`), so as long as you are sure that all elements have fixed positioning and sizeing (like `position: relative;top: ;left: ;'`) then ok, but try to resize your site - see what happens? Parent element should has `position: relative;`

Comment: nice , got the point . Thank you . see your around :-)

Comment: -1.  This answer doesn't provide any description of how you solved the problem.  It will also be useless if/when the jsFiddle expires.
If you can add a description of how you solved the problem, I will remove my downvote.